# How to make each cell editable on a button click in jquery data table

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using jquery datatable. There is a button in each row. Now I want to make each cells editable of a row when I clicked that button of that row.

Comment: what you tried so far?

Comment: adding button in each row

Comment: provide a [mcve]

Comment: but your question asks for *How to make each cell editable on a button click in jquery data table* not for adding button in each row.. BTW , you will need a click event for the button and use `.closest('tr')` to select the button's row and `.each()` to loop through the elements which you want to make it editable

Comment: give me an example how to use .closet and .each()

Comment: Google will provides you all the examples you need.

Answer (score 0):

Please look into the following sample code.

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#requestTable tr').hover(function () {
        $(this).addClass('hover');
    }, function () {
        $(this).removeClass('hover');
    });

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#requestTable tr td").click(function () {
            alert("Make This td editable :" + jQuery(this).closest('tr').find('.txt').text());

        });
    });
</script>
 </head>
<body>
<form>
    <div>
        <table class="table" id="requestTable">
            <thead class="text-primary">
                <th>Column</th>
                <th>Button</th>

            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr class="row">
                    <td class="txt">@item.interfacename</td>
                    <td>Button 1</td>
                </tr>
                  <tr class="row">

                    <td class="txt">@item.interfacename 1</td>
                      <td>Button 2</td>
                </tr>
                  <tr class="row">

                    <td class="txt">@item.interfacename 2</td>
                      <td>Button 3</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</form>
</body>
<html>
```

In the above sample code i am showing alert for td which was placed in the row whose button is clicked. So you can customize this code according to your need.

Hope it will help you.